# Int or Unsigned Int to float without getting a warning

Tags: c++

Sometimes I have to convert from an unsigned integer value to a float. For example, my graphics engine takes in a `SetScale(float x, float y, float z)` with floats and I have an object that has a certain size as an `unsigned int`. I want to convert the unsigned int to a float to properly scale an entity (the example is very specific but I hope you get the point).

Now, what I usually do is:

```
unsigned int size = 5;
float scale = float(size);
My3DObject->SetScale(scale , scale , scale);
```

Is this good practice at all, under certain assumptions (see Notes)? Is there a better way than to litter the code with `float()`?

> **Notes:** I cannot touch the graphics API. I have to use the SetScale() function which takes in floats. Moreover, I also cannot touch the size, it has to be an unsigned int. I am sure there are plenty of other examples with the same 'problem'. The above can be applied to any conversion that needs to be done and you as a programmer have little choice in the matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion from `unsigned int` to `float`, so the cast is strictly unnecessary.

If your compiler issues a warning, then there isn't really anything wrong with using a cast to silence the warning.  Just be aware that if `size` is very large it may not be representable exactly by a `float`.

Comment: This will barf warnings like an 18 year old at a hazing on my compiler at the highest settings.

Comment: Yes, MS VC++ 10 warns for this.  Deleted my answer as the cast is needed to get rid of those.

Comment: @John:  Some compilers barf warnings at everything.  Intel C++ at `/W5` issues a warning if the storage class specifier is not the first keyword in a declaration (e.g., `const static int x;` is bad but `static const int x;` is fine).  :-)

Comment: This is Visual Studio 2008 at warning level 3

Answer (score 11):

My preference would be to use `static_cast`:

```
float scale = static_cast<float>(size);
```

but what you are doing is functionally equivalent and fine.