# Getting rid of warning messages related to int32_t conversion from float C++

Tags: c++, compilation

I have gotten hold of some C++ game sources, I am pretty new to C++ and I have compiled the sources successfully and it appears to work fine, however there are some annoying warnings I just can't get to solve.

My C++ programming skills are very basic, and I have big problems with these template variable thingys. Especially this modular template called int32_t, which appears to be used pretty much everywhere in my sources.

Documentation I read upon int32_t are not exacly noob friendly, they are very formal and really hard to understand for those who do not know how to use it. (And ummh, I feel I might actually be looking at the wrong places).

**To the point:**

Here is the function I am having problems with:

```
int32_t Weapons::getMaxMeleeWeaponDamage(int32_t attackSkill, int32_t attackValue, float attackFactor)
{
    return ((int32_t)std::ceil(((attackValue * 0.05) * attackSkill) + (attackValue)) / attackFactor);
}
```

**Warnings given:**

170 C:\compiling\GameSources\weapons.cpp [Warning] converting to `int32_t' from`float'

The clue is, I do want it to calculate taking float into consideration, and return an int value.
(So damage calculations are accurate, but the damage display on the game client returns the integer representation of the damage).

So as far as I know, this warning is merely telling me what I want to hear. But how can I get rid of this warning? (Beside telling my compiler to ignore warnings, I dont want that).

Comment: The warning just lets you know you might be doing something wrong, if you know you're doing everything right then you can silence the warning. Similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262158/int-or-unsigned-int-to-float-without-getting-a-warning

Answer (score 2):

You are converting the return value of ceil to an int. Then you divide that result by a float. What you have now, the value you return, is a float. The compile then has to convert that to an int. It is the latter conversion the compiler complains about.

I would say you have misplaced the type casting.

As a style issue, I would suggest that you use C++ casting instead of the old C-style casting.